# Postfix wont send mail to external email addresses listed in virtual_alias_domains

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, wildcard

We have our main server at `mail.mainserver.com` with the catchall address `catch@mail.mainserver.com`

We also have two other domains: domain1.com and domain2.com which are hosted at gmail. Gmail is re-routing catchall emails to catch@mainserver.com

In /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com, domain2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And in /etc/postfix/virtual

```
@mail.mainserver.com catch@mail.mainserver.com
@domain1.com catch@mail.mainserver.com
@domian2.com catch@mail.mainserver.com
```

These settings are working when it comes to receiving email to either of the above domains, but the issue we are having is in sending an email from a virtual alias ie `testoutgoing@mail.mainserver.com` to an existing mailbox at gmail ie `existing@domain1.com`

The email is not sent, instead it is placed into the inbox of catch@mail.mainserver.com

Is there any way to create an ignore list, so that postfix ignores checks on the virtual alias table for specific email addresses and sends them as it would to any other external email address?

Thanks in advance.

As requested, here's our complete config:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.mainserver.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = mail.mainserver.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhostname
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com,domain2.com
allow_percent_hack = no
swap_bangpath = no
mydomain = mainserver.com
mynetworks_style = host
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
# smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
delay_warning_time = 0h
maximal_queue_lifetime = 4h
bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
queue_run_delay = 300s
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
enable_original_recipient = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
allow_min_user = no
message_size_limit = 15728640
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
#virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist_recipients
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = ./dovecot-auth
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
luser_relay = catch@mail.mainserver.com
local_recipient_maps =
```

Comment: What makes you say that @eichertc ?

Comment: this is impossible. what are the MX entries of domain1.com and domain2.com, they can not be the same time pointing to google and to your server.

Comment: Did you even read the above post?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal.

If domain1.com and domain2.com are hosted at google, you can't write them in your server virtual_alias_domains.

If you put them there in the virtual_alias_domains you tell your postfix he is responsible for this domains and then he see that he has to send any email that has destination domain1.com or domain2.com to catch@mail.mainserver.com

and thats what he is doing.

---

please post the output of `postconf -nf` , `postconf -Mf` and eventually `dovecot -n`.

> Is there no way to add some kind of whitelist,

whitelist is a wrong term.
(it is related to spam filtering.)

but why don't you simple do what I said, comment out

```
# virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com,domain2.com
```

or remove the line completely
same like

```
# @domain1.com catch@mail.mainserver.com
# @domian2.com catch@mail.mainserver.com
```

comment them out or remove them.

If domain1.com,domain2.com are hosted at google and you expect the server mail.mainserver.com to send the emails for these two domains to google, then this will not happen if the domains are real, virtual or alias domains on the server mail.mainserver.com.

The server will not sent them away because he feels responsible for this two domains. In addition your /etc/postfix/virtual say that any mail for domain1.com should be forwarded to catch@mail.mainserver.com same like any mail for domain domian2.com should be forwarded to catch@mail.mainserver.com. This is why any emails for this two domains land in the INBOX of catch@mail.mainserver.com.

> or force postfix to send all emails externally?

if you want to forward everything externally you can:

a) put a outside email in your /etc/postfix/virtual

```
@mail.mainserver.com existing@domain1.com
```

b) use a  [.forward](http://www.feep.net/sendmail/tutorial/intro/forward.html) file

c) install procmail and make a /etc/procmailrc with the following content

```
#
# Forward everything to existing@domain1.com
#
:0:
! existing@domain1.com
```

d) if you feel more yippee, install use dovecot/sieve and write a rule to redirect all emails to the foreign server. Sieve is a bit hairy to configure, if you have problems with the first 3 methods you prolly will not succeed this one.

```
#
# Forward everything coming from testoutgoing@mail.mainserver.com
# to existing@domain1.com
#
if address :is ["From"] "testoutgoing@mail.mainserver.com"  {
  redirect "existing@domain1.com"; 
  stop;
}
```

there may be also other methods but these are in my opinion the simplest.

Comment: Is there no way to add some kind of whitelist, or force postfix to send all emails externally?